# Square of convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If series $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum a_n^{2}$ diverges, prove that $\sum a_n$ converges under certain conditions and give an example of such series.
Any idea on how to prove this?
I tried to use tests for convergence, to possibly get closer to result to see what $a_n$ should be. But I am completely lost.

Comment: I think the structure of the question points in the direction that $\sum {a_n}^2$ is a series of positive terms only. If it diverges and $\sum a_n$ converges, surely $\sum a_n$ is not a series of only positive terms. Can you see why?

Comment: I actually thought that possible solution for $a_n$ are alternating series. I tried to come up with an example, but it turned out they weren't correct. If $a_n$ was positive and converged, then surely $a_n^{2}$ too would converge.

Comment: $\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$ is one such example

Comment: Ah yes, this is what I came up with. But I guess I forgot that this example converges. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: If $\sum_na_n$ converges, you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. This means that for all sufficiently large $n$, $|a_n|<1$, and therefore $a_n^2<|a_n|$. Thus, if the terms $a_n$ were positive, $\sum_na_n^2$ would have to converge even faster than $\sum_na_n$. But we’re told that $\sum_na_n^2$ diverges. This means that the $a_n$ cannot all be positive. They can’t even all be positive for all sufficiently large $n$. Nor can they all be negative from some point on. (Why?) What kind of convergent series must $\sum_na_n$ therefore be? Once you see that, it’s not hard to come up with an example.